# Better way to visualize a very dense scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with sarcasm dataset from reddit. The two main columns are the `text` and the `sarcasm_tag`. I have added two more columns to the dataframe, `positive_score` and `negative_score`. Where both represent the scores of positive and negative sentiment respectively. In order to visualize this distribution of the score, I plotted a scatter plot, which looks like this
[image]

Since the text with `sarcasm_tag == Yes` are very less, it hides many points on the graph. Separate plot for both tags are as follows:
[image]

[image]

Is there any better way to visualize the scores so that both classes are visible?

Comment: You could plot the "No" points first, then overlay the "Yes" points after.  You might have to ditch the legend, or tweak it manually though.

Comment: That worked. Didn't think of doing that, thanks.

Comment: You could try a logarithmic scale as well to space out the data that is clumped around the lower values.

Comment: I think the best way is to discard the scatter plot and switch to a 2d histogram. That way, you'll be able to plot heatmaps that will give you a better sense of the densities than the overlapping scattered markers

Comment: Also you can cut a little x_lim and y_lim to make the margins of the plot smaller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [win](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) solution (plot second no points) you can play with the `alpha` of the points, to give more color to the no.

```
# Sample data
blue_data = np.random.normal(size=(3000, 2))
red_data = np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))

for blue_point in blue_data:
    plt.plot(blue_point[0], blue_point[1], 'ob')
for red_point in red_data:
    plt.plot(red_point[0], red_point[1], 'or')
```

[image]

With 0.3 alpha for the blues, and 0.8 alpha for the reds

```
for blue_point in blue_data:
    plt.plot(blue_point[0], blue_point[1], 'ob', alpha=0.3)
for red_point in red_data:
    plt.plot(red_point[0], red_point[1], 'or', alpha=0.8)
```

[image]

Best! You can play with the alpha until you find what you are looking for.